# minimization optimization problem with equality constraints

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier, constraints

I would like to find the optimal solution to the optimization problem:

$\min_x  x^TMx+c^Tx$

s.t  $Ax=b$

where M is PD, A is m over n matrix, M is n over n matrix, x and c are n-dimensional vectors over R and b is m-dimensinal vector over R .

I defined the Lagrangian:

$L(x,\lambda)= x^TMx+c^Tx+ \lambda(Ax-b)$

and then I derivated it:

$\nabla_x L(x,\lambda)= x^T(M+M^T)+c^T+ \lambda A =0$

But I failed to continue,
I will highly appriciate some help, thank you.

Comment: You may assume $M=M^T$ otherwise set $M\leftarrow \frac12(M+M^T)$. To continue: solve $\nabla_xL=0$ for $x$, set into $Ax=b$ and solve for $\lambda$. Note $\lambda$ is a vector.

Comment: or just add $Ax=b$ to the inequality you already have and solve for both $x$ and $\lambda$